# Rails: Split fields_for for same instance in a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-many, fields-for

In order to have a coherent experience, I need to create a form which splits fields for an associated model. For a has_one association it works perfectly, however for a has_many, things go south.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pages
  acceptes_nested_attributes_for :pages
end
```

--

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
end
```

--

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @book = Book.new
    @page = @book.pages.build
  end
end
```

--

new.html.slim

```
= form_for @book do |f|
  # normal book fields

  = fields_for :pages, @page do |p|
    p.text_field :title
    p.number_field :title_size

  # some more book fields

  HERE'S THE CATCH. I need to add some more fields for THE SAME PAGE

  = fields_for :pages, @page do |p|
    p.text_area :body
    p.number_field :page_number
```

---

The thing is, when I send the form, in my strong params I get as many indices as fields_for I write.

```
ActionController::Parameters{... "pages_attributes" => "0" => {"title"=> "","title_size"=> ""}, "1" => { "body"=> "", "page_number"=> "" } }
```

0 and 1 in Actioncontroller::Parameters correspond to each fields_for I place, even though I am specifically using the record_object attribute with @page. I need all of those `fields_for` to correspond to the same instance.

What am I doing wrong? I'm out of options now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use rails 4 or higher, take a look at [strong parametrs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Comment: I am, its not a strong_params issue. I didn't type that in the example for brevity.

Comment: `fields_for` is not intended to be used in this way. It iterates through a `has_many` association. You could probally use the captures helper to provide fields for the second "area" from a single `fields_for` block. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html

Comment: Hey @max! I don't quite get how you would use the captures helper in this case. Could you give me some pointers?

Comment: @pinzonjulian did you find a solution?

Comment: Not exactly. I'm using a completely different solution by using form objects to create my own structures. Although I'm building my own, take a look at Reform by the guys at Trailblazer.